# Kendo Grid MVC Razor - column formating

Tags: kendo-grid

I have the following code on my cshmtl:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIMvcApplication3.Models.Parts>()
        .Name("grdParent")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(o => o.PartNo).Title("Part No").ClientTemplate("<a href='javascript:' onclick=\"OnSelectBtnClick1('#= PartNo#')\" >#= PartNo #</a>").Width(80);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Decription).Title("Part Description").Width(180);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Price).Title("Price").Width(30);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Consignment).Title("Consign").Hidden(true).Width(20);
                columns.Bound(o => o.Cat).Title("Cat").Width(10).Hidden(true);
            })
            .Scrollable()
            .Selectable(selectable => selectable
                .Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
                .Type(GridSelectionType.Row))
            .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
            .Events(events => events
                .DataBound("onDatabound"))
            
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Home")))
            .ClientDetailTemplateId("Detail")
            )
```

And the following is in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.3.1316/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.3.1316/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.3.1316/kendo.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2013.3.1316/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If I include the .Scrollable(), the columns in my grid does not format correctly - see image attached.  Can anyone help me on how to solve this issue?  thanks.

[image: sample]

Comment: Looks to me like your ClientDetailTemplate is scrunching the data somehow. Have a look back at the kendoUI examples and make sure you aren't doing something funky: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/detailtemplate.html

Comment: Could you post the code for your detail template?